# How do I set the Publisher when creating a Tauri WIndows App?

Tags: tauri

I have not been able to set the publisher when creating the windows installer using Tauri. IT just shows Unknown publisher when I try installing. How do I go about customizing the installer? Also setting the image to be used, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be an explicit tauri.conf.json setting for that in the next release (v1.2): https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/pull/5283 - Currently it just defaults to the middle part of the configured bundle identifier.

*But* because we're talking about Windows, the publisher will only be displayed if you sign the app! Tauri specific docs about code signing are here: https://tauri.app/v1/guides/distribution/sign-windows

> Also setting the image to be used, etc.

See this config https://tauri.app/v1/api/config#wixconfig, most images the installer shows are configurable with that one.